# Component: 'WSL Kernel' Error Code: 0x80072f7d on wsl --install

Tags: windows-10, macos, windows-subsystem-for-linux, parallels

I'm trying to install the Windows Subsystem for Linux within an updated Windows 10 VM (in Parallels on a MacBook), but it partially fails:

```
C:\Windows\system32>wsl --install
Installing: Windows Subsystem for Linux
Windows Subsystem for Linux has been installed.
Downloading: WSL Kernel
A error was encountered during installation, but installation may continue. Component: 'WSL Kernel' Error Code: 0x80072f7d
Downloading: Ubuntu
The requested operation is successful. Changes will not be effective until the system is rebooted.
```

WSL gets installed, but the Kernel not. After restart the cmd opens with this output:

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x800701bc
Error: 0x800701bc WSL 2 requires an update to its kernel component. For information please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2kernel

Press any key to continue...
```

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Just a thought - As long as you are enabling WSL in a Win10 VM, I'd recommend going ahead and making it Win11.  The WSL upgrades in Windows 11 are pretty nice and seems stable at this point, just a few days away from GA.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thank you for your suggestion. I will go for Win11 in the future for sure, no matter what. Regarding this issue, it was fine to explore, but as a Mac user I think it's way better to just install Ubuntu on Parallels, instead of installing WSL on Windows, especially, because you don't need to own Parallels Pro/Business. Though, there might be legit reasons to use WSL in Windows on Parallels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to own the Pro/Business version of Parallels and then you need to [enable nested virtualization](https://kb.parallels.com/en/125195). I removed WSL in "Add or remove program features", restarted and attempted to install WSL once more with `wsl --install` after enabling nested virtualization and it worked eventually.

Quote:

> Using Nested Virtualization is essential to use WSL2 and the brand new Windows Docker for WSL2.

Source: https://patrickwu.space/2020/02/14/wsl-on-mac/

Answer (score 2):

Naaaah,

1. Go to [https://aka.ms/wsl2kernel](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package) and download the **WSL2 Linux kernel update package for x64 machines**
2. Now execute the file, you should see this:

[image]

3. And now run your Ubuntu/Debian/Whatever

Follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgk7yMkrDRk) if you have problems

Answer (score -2):

In cmd, run:

```bash
netsh winsock reset
```

than rerun with:

```bash
wsl --install -d Ubuntu
```

It will be OK.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).